# Sandy Bridge QPI bandwidth perf event

Tags: profiling, intel, bandwidth, perf, numa

I'm trying to find the proper raw perf event descriptor to monitor QPI traffic (bandwidth) on Intel Xeon E5-2600 (Sandy Bridge).

I've found an event that seems relative [here](https://relate.cs.illinois.edu/course/cs598apk-f18/f/demos/upload/perf/Using%20Performance%20Counters.html) (`qpi_data_bandwidth_tx`: Number of data flits transmitted . Derived from `unc_q_txl_flits_g0.data`. Unit: `uncore_qpi`) but I can't use it in my system. So probably these events refer to a different micro-architecture.

Moreover, I've looked into the "*[Intel ® Xeon ® Processor E5-2600 Product Family Uncore Performance Monitoring Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/design-guides/xeon-e5-2600-uncore-guide.pdf)*" and the most relative reference I found is the following:

```
To calculate "data" bandwidth, one should therefore do: 
data flits * 8B / time (for L0) 
or 4B instead of 8B for L0p
```

The events that monitor the data flits are:

1. RxL_FLITS_G0.DATA
2. RxL_FLITS_G1.DRS_DATA
3. RxL_FLITS_G2.NCB_DATA

Q1: Are those the correct events?

Q2: If yes, should I monitor all these events and add them in order to get the total data flits or just the first?

Q3: I don't quite understand in what the `8B` and `time` refer to.

Q4: Is there any way to validate?

Also, please feel free to suggest alternatives in monitoring QPI traffic bandwidth in case there are any.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A Xeon E5-2600 processor has two QPI ports, each port can send up to one flit and receive up to one flit per QPI domain clock cycle. Not all flits carry data, but all non-idle flits consume bandwidth. It seems to me that you're interested in counting only data flits, which is useful for detecting remote access bandwdith bottlenecks at the socket level (instead of a particular agent within a socket).

The event `RxL_FLITS_G0.DATA` can be used to count the number of data flits received. This is equal to the sum of `RxL_FLITS_G1.DRS_DATA` and `RxL_FLITS_G2.NCB_DATA`. You only need to measure the latter two events if you care about the break down. Note that there are only 4 event counter per QPI port. The event `TxL_FLITS_G0.DATA` can be used to count the number of data flits transmitted to other sockets.

The events `RxL_FLITS_G0.DATA` and `TxL_FLITS_G0.DATA` can be used to measure the total number of flits transferred through the specified port. So it takes two out of the four counts available in each port to count total data flits.

There is no accurate way to convert data flits to bytes. A flit may contain up to 8 valid bytes. This depends on the type of transaction and power state of the link direction (power states are per link per direction). A good estimate can be obtained by reasonably assuming that most data flits are part of full cache line packets and are being transmitted in the L0 power state, so each flit does contains exactly 8 valid bytes. Alternatively, you can just measure port utilization in terms of data flits rather than bytes.

The unit of time is up to you. Ultimately, if you want to determine whether QPI bandwdith is a bottleneck, the bandwdith has to be measured periodically and compared against the theoretical maximum bandwidth. You can, for example, use total QPI clock cycles, which can be counted on one of the free QPI port PMU counters. The QPI frequency is fixed on JKT.

For validation, you can write a simple program that allocates a large buffer in remote memory and reads it. The measured number of bytes should be about the same as the size of the buffer in bytes.

Comment: On Sandy Bridge-EP, I had good results with both TxL_FLITS and RxL_FLITS events in cross-socket testing with the STREAM benchmark.  RxL_FLITS_G1.DRS_DATA*8 was within 1% of the expected traffic in Bytes.
On Haswell-EP, the RxL_FLITS_G1.DRS_DATA values were bad -- about a factor of 2 too low, but the TxL_FLITS_G1.DRS_DATA values were fine.